# reasonable window allowed for successful network response

Tags: android, networking

I'm implementing the Play Integrity API.

I already do all checks documentation suggests.

In the integrity response there is `timestampMillis`, [documented](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#request-details-field) as:

> The timestamp in milliseconds when the request was made (computed on the server).

I'll compare it to the current timestamp in order to know the freshness of the response, and to avoid/slow down hacking attempts.

The official documentation does not suggest the ideal allowed window to check it, because it may depends on various factors.

Without considering the case when the user's connection is slow or unstable, which causes an empty/failed response that I'll handle with an exponential retry, what should be the maximum time allowable for a **success response**?

I'm not asking for an opinion based answer but for an answer backed by some technical factors.

Comment: As the technical factors determining the maximum allowed response time are hidden by the Play Integrity API, we cannot safely assume a response is legitimate based solely on the response time. As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#nonce) suggests, you should be utilizing the `nonce` field to ensure integrity. There are multiple strategies described at a high level in the documentation.

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav I already do all checks documentation suggests, I'm concerned only about the timestamp.

Comment: I used to give the simple answer that a read timeout should be twice as long as the expected service time. On consideration I have started recommending that a TCP read timeout should be two or three standard deviations above the mean service interval, so that you capture 95% or 99% of correct cases while detecting the rogue cases. Either way you need to gather some actual statistics.

Answer (score -1):

The lower bound should be valued by the maximum time required to establish a TCP connection. The upper bound is restricted only by the business rules and the time required to spend cracking the cryptography behind it.

From the security perspective, if somebody starts DDOSing your server (accidentally due to a bug in a DNS/BGP configuration, or on purpose), it's a good idea to filter out requests by `ALLOWED_WINDOW_MILLIS`, before doing CPU-heavy computations.

Comment: Which are the values for TCP_USER_TIMEOUT and SO_KEEPALIVE?

Comment: They are environment dependent. A webserver like Nginx (or your own) may set them in its configs. Also, there are [system-wide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222538/how-were-these-linux-tcp-default-settings-decided) configs. Basically, when a server program establishes a connection and opens a socket, it can define all those parameters.

Comment: (1) `TCP_USER_TIMEOUT` is not a timeout value. It is the name of a socket option which enables write timeouts. (2) `SO_KEEPALIVE` is not a timeout value. It is the name of a socket option that *enables* TCP keepalive, whose default timeout is two hours, which is far too long to use as a 'lower bound'. Your answer therefore does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I'm not a kernel expert, so I appreciate any improvements on the answer. Even so, the point is that a three-way handshake + reliable data transfer requires time, which should be accounted for.